# What is the word that defines walking confidently, coldly and calmly?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, idioms

Is there a word for walking confidently, coldly and calmly...but not angrily, frustrated or in a rush. And not a fake self-confident walk to make people believe you are an important person.

Comment: ***Stride*** has many other usages, but it's common to say such a person [***strode** confidently*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22strode+confidently%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: *Stroll*, *March*, or *Paced*.

Comment: Strut is the first word that comes to mind.

Comment: *Strut* seems too ostentatious to me, and *stroll* seems too leisurely.

Comment: Google finished my "walked with c..." with ***conviction***.

Comment: Re: [What does “bore down” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/what-does-bore-down-mean) Hellion's answer: *"to bear down on (something)" generally has the meaning of approaching 'in a threatening manner'.* If they're coming at me like you say; I'm getting out of the way.

Comment: I'm drawing a blank. Are you referring to an [ominous walk](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OminousWalk)?

Comment: When a question attracts a long list of answers, that usually means it is subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has one clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Answer (score 4):

I would use ***swagger***. However, I also think ***stride*** is a good one, as  FumbleFingers say. ***Strut*** may also work. You can also say ***walking with aplomb***

Comment: [Swagger](https://www.google.com/search?q=swagger&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is aggressive or arrogant. To [stride](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stride) is to take very long steps. To [strut](https://www.google.com/search?q=strut&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) is arrogant or conceited. So, -3.

Comment: @Mazura In the question, the poster specifies that it should not imply "angrily, frustrated, or in a rush. And not fake self-confident" but there is no mention to arrogance or true self-confidence. Could you please elaborate a bit more and explain why swagger or strut don't qualify?

Comment: @Mazura: And I still consider FumbleFingers "stride" a valid suggestion, specially when used as "stride with conviction" or "stride purposefully". Stride, by the way, also means "to walk with long regular or measured paces".

Comment: My downvote was figurative. I was just hoping you'd provide definitions and examples you thought appropriate. I do like *aplomb.*, however it's the fourth answer to a SWR that I don't like two of. Stride is good but it has to *strode*.

Answer (score 3):

***[Saunter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saunter)*** does not indicate confidence but does indicate lack of anger/frustration/hurry.
(M-W)

Comment: I like saunter for this!

Answer (score 2):

To me, to walk ***"purposefully"*** connotes a vision of someone looking straight ahead, in control and with a purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't have the rep to comment, and nobody has made it their main answer, let me chime in with ***Stride***.

It has more meaning than just long steps. The usage that immediately comes to mind is:

*in stride*
1 without interference with regular activities
2 without emotional reaction

also:
*Stride*
1b the most effective natural pace :  maximum competence or capability
—often used in the phrase hit one's stride
[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stride)

The connotation of stride is more in line with what you asked (calm) than any of the other answers (though all of them are good, most of them convey some more intense level of emotion).

Answer (score 0):

To do something "confidently, coldly and calmly" is to do so ***with conviction***.

**conviction** [kuh n-vik-shuh n] noun -[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conviction)

> 1. a fixed or firm belief

*The spec ops team deployed themselves about the battlefield with conviction.*

Answer (score 0):

[authority](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/authority)

*noun*

> 3.1 The confidence resulting from personal expertise:
>
> *he hit the ball with authority*

You could say "*she walked across the room **with authority**.*"

[like a boss](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/like-a-boss)

> **Like A Boss** is a catchphrase often used in image macros or GIFs that
>   feature a person completing an action with authority and finesse.

If you are willing to use slang, you could say "*She walked across the room **like a boss**.*"

> When my parents get mad at me for lying I say 'Santa Claus, Easter
>   Bunny, and The Toothfairy.' Then [walk away like a boss](http://www.someecards.com/usercards/unsubmitted/MjAxMi03MTVmYzg0YzQ2OWI5MDM4).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would submit **stalk** as a good option. It can have the feeling of confidence, coldness, and calmness, but it can be quite terrifying to those surrounding the person.

**Jaunt** can also convey the confidence and calmness but is not really for a cold demeanor, generally it has a more happy uplifted feel. A spring in the step.

**Pace** could be used with appropriate adverbs. It's neutral but not overused. In the wrong context it can feel furtive, like if a person is pacing a room, but in a different context you could say *he stately **paced** down the boulevard until he reached the cafe.*

**Advance** depending on context could have all those qualities you are looking for, such as *he **advanced** on the stranger.*

**March** has a confidence and calmness and distinct coldness about it but it comes with a bit of military flair and rigidity, but it doesn't necessarily involve goosestepping everywhere.

If your going for an aristocratic coldness i.e. disdain, **parade** is a great option, especially if you aren't looking to go anywhere quickly; and I would hazard to say that many aristocrats (depending on setting) don't *think* they are important they know they are important as only someone born and bred to it could be and they like to show it off.

In the right context **traverse** could be used as it has a confident flavor, in that it is out of the norm and only a well-educated person would use it. It is inherently a neutral word but it's Latin and French roots give it the aforementioned flavor, you can thank the Normans for that.

And as mentioned before **stride** should not be discounted. It is most certainly a confident and purposeful action and with that is inherently calmness; and with the right adverb, you can certainly get your coldness.

Answer (score -3):

"Bearing".

E.g. "Sailor, stand straight and maintain your bearing at all times!".

Comment: *Bearing* can be " the way in which a person moves, stands, or behaves" but it does not refer specifically to a calm, confident presentation....

Comment: @Hellion I disagree, especially in a military setting.  Actual usage of the word bearing most definitely includes a calm and confident demeanor.  From the Naval Officer Candidate School Leadership traits: "Bearing - Creating a favorable impression in carriage, appearance and personal conduct at all times."

Comment: But *bearing* must be modified.  "regal" bearing, "stately" bearing, "confident" bearing etc.  In your example we are maintaining a presumably confident, considered, measured ... bearing.

Answer (score -3):

How about boring, no seriously - someone could bore through a crowd indicating not anger or haste just determination.

Comment: I never heard boring for anything other than staring a hole into someone with their eyes or literally boring a hole - but never for walking! :-)